# Searching for the search box

Tags: feature-request, help-center

The help topic [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) states:

> Enter search terms in the search box that appears in the **upper right corner** of every page,

Here is a picture of the upper-right corner of the page that statement appears on, showing that the search box is not there:

[image: Upper-right corner, no search box]

And the presentation of the search facility on the home page is different on my mobile phone:

[image: Mobile phone search button]

... so I suppose some more words are needed in the documentation for the search on the main pages on mobile devices.

**Request:** Please could the documentation be updated to reflect the current location of the search box: sort-of in the middle at the top of the page. (Hopefully someone can come up with better wording than that.)

Comment: I wonder why the documentation wants to be so specific about telling where it is rather than just "in the top navigation bar" ? Was it to aid people who do not see very well / at all?

Comment: @Gimby I think "in the top navigation bar" is a very good way of describing its location. As for people using screen readers, it does have `role="search"` in its markup, so I imagine it is easy to find for them.